# Why did Beverly cut her hair?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-2017

In the Hollywood horror movie *It* (2017), which is based on a novel by Stephen King, the young girl Beverly who lives with her abusive father is shown cutting her hair in front of mirror.

Why does she do this?

What is the significance of this scene? I want to know if I have missed out any other significant details related to the scene.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scene exactly before Beverly cuts her hair in the bathroom is with her father who is standing creepily in the hallway and notices the sanitary pads (I think) in her hand and then creepily caress her hair saying something like:

> "You're still my little girl aren't you Bev".

She cuts her hair because she doesn't want to look like a girl. In a later scene, her father points out her boyish looks and is annoyed.

Comment: Also worth noting that as she was cutting her hair she was whispering "See what you did? You did this" (at least that's the way it was dubbed). This might also indicate the fact that she thought he had tainted her hair by caressing it (she cut off exactly the part he had touched).

Comment: That might be an answer in itself, @ruslaniv.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting that as she was cutting her hair she was whispering:

> "*See what you did? You did this*" (at least that's the way it was dubbed).

This might also indicate the fact that she thought he had tainted her hair by caressing it (she cut off exactly the part he had touched).